# How to pass string array data to navigationLink in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, foreach, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm using SwiftUI and having some problem passing my string array to a view.
Let's me explain the situation. I'm working on a Gallery app to show some artist's paintings.
I create a TabView to show all the paintings from each artist without any problem but I wanted to make each paintings clickable to see the detail view of the painting, and this where I get stuck.
Every time I click on a paintings it's show me the same paintings...

here is the samples code:

Model & View Model

```
 let artistData: [Artist] = [
    Artist(
        name: "Piotre",
        profilePic: "Piotre",
        biography: "Piotre, est un...",
        worksImages: [
            "GO LOVE YOUR SELF 115.5-89",
            "GRAFFITI THERAPIE 146-226",
            "HELLO MY NAME IS  130-162",
            "KING'S GARDEN 162-130",
            "LION'S GARDEN 100-100",
            "R'S GARDEN 162 130"
        ],
        workName: [
            "GO LOVE YOUR SELF",
            "GRAFFITI THERAPIE",
            "HELLO MY NAME IS",
            "KING'S GARDEN",
            "LION'S GARDEN",
            "R'S GARDEN"
        ], workSize: [
            "115.5-89",
            "146-226",
            "130-162",
            "162-130",
            "100-100",
            "162 130"
        ]),
]


    struct Artist: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var profilePic: String
    var biography: String
    var worksImages: [String]
    var workName: [String]
    var workSize: [String]
}



struct ArtistGalleryView: View {
    //MARK:- PROPERTIES
    var work: Artist
    
    //MARK:- BODY
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.6549019608, green: 0.7137254902, blue: 0.862745098, alpha: 1)).opacity(0.2)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                //MARK:- Tableaux
                TabView {
                    ForEach(work.worksImages, id: \.self) { works in
                        Image(works)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            }
                            .padding()
                        }
                        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 330, height: 400, alignment: .center)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
           
        }
    }

struct GalleryView: View {
    //MARK:- PROPERTIES
    var artist: [Artist] = artistData
    
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont(name: "WorkSans-Bold", size: 20)!]
    }
    //MARK:- BODY
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(artist) { item in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            ArtistName(artist: item)
                            NavigationLink(destination: WorksDetailView(work: item)) {
                                ArtistGalleryView(work: item)
                            }
                         }
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:Button(action: {
                
            }) {

            }
            )
             .navigationBarTitle(
                    Text("Gallery"), displayMode: .inline)
            }
        }
}
```

And my detail view where I want to see the corresponding image

```
struct WorksDetailView: View {
    @State private var moveUp = false
   
    var work: Artist
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(work.workName[0])
                    .modifier(CustomFontModifier(size: 22, name: "WorkSans-Bold"))
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                Text(work.workSize[0])
                    .modifier(CustomFontModifier(size: 17, name: "WorkSans-Light"))
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            VStack {
                Image(work.worksImages[0])
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    }
                    .padding()
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .padding(.bottom, 150)
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Show AR")
            }) {
                NeumorphicButton(moveUp: $moveUp)
                }
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
                        moveUp.toggle()
                    }
                })
                .offset(y: moveUp ? 225 : 450)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provided code shows always first image `Image(work.worksImages[0])`, so you get what you coded.

Comment: Asperi is correct (I seem to say that a lot),  but I think the issue you are having coming up with the correct code is that you don't have a clear data model. You have an Artist type that contains art the artist has done (works), but, when you go to reference a single work, you define it as an Artist which has multiple works. A work should be just that, a single work of art. Since you are using strings, just make work a String, not an artist, and pass just THAT work to your detail view. I will leave the implementation of that to you.